# V-validate not working with interpolated attribute

Tags: javascript, html, validation, vue.js, vee-validate

When I use a static attribute, validation errors appear as expected:

```
<input type="number" name="phone" v-validate="'required|digits:10'">
<span>{{ errors.first(propertyName) }}</span>
```

But what if I don't want to hardcode the validation rules in the JavaScript? I would think this would work:

```
<input type="number" name="phone" :v-validate="phone.rules">
<span>{{ errors.first(propertyName) }}</span>
```

But no validation errors are appearing. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created jsFiddle and everything seems to work fine. Feel free to check:
https://jsfiddle.net/m67d8f4x/2032/

```
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" v-validate="rules.rule" v-model="email">
// js
  data() {
    return {
      rules: { rule: 'required' },
      email: ''
    }
  },
```

Comment: This helped me realize that the `v-validate` property accepts objects without requiring a colon (`:v-validate`), which was my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to remove the colon from the v-validate property, and then the object worked. I.e. use `v-validate` instead of `:v-validate`. I was confused, because using JavaScript with other Vue attributes requires a colon.